# javascript function is not getting fired in jsf 2

Tags: javascript, jsf

I want to add this code in JSF create.xhtml page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function  setValueZero(id){

         document.getElementById(id).value = "0";

         }

        </script>
```

I have called this function in textbox.

```
<p:inputText id="debitAmount" value="#{jvDetailsController.selected.debitAmount}" onkeypress="setValueZero('creditAmount');">
```

But this function is not being fired? Can someone suggest me solution please? where to keep this script tag?

Comment: Please post how the HTML was rendered via right click view source

Comment: I have done. can u please check now?

Comment: where is field with id `creditAmount` ? put alert inside function to make sure is your function call is problematic or your get element statement getting faild

Comment: @awesum - i dont see your rendered html posted

Comment: alert is not working as well.Is there any other tag except script for javascript in JSF?

Answer (score 0):

`setValueZero` is not `setvalueZero` the "V" is capital on one and not on the other

Comment: No, its correct in my code.. I did mistake while writing here.. Is there any other tag except script for javascript in JSF?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `onkeypress="setValueZero('creditAmount');"` with `onkeypress="alert('hello')"`

If you see the alert popup it means that the `onkeypress` works fine and its your js code is located in a *wrong place of your page*.

Best practice would be to write your code in a js file and include it with `<h:outputScript`

Take a look at this tutorial [How To Include JavaScript File In JSF](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-javascript-file-in-jsf/) and even better if you read this one [Resources (Library) In JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/)

Comment: I did exactly a/c to that tutorial but it's still not working..why is that so?

Comment: maybe you have a typo in folder/file/function name , take a look at the browser console... it should work...